# What is the proper technique to get the eigenvector values?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have found the eigenvector for this matrix with eigenvalue 9. I tried Wolfram Alpha and the answer was (3,4) and my answer is (0.75,1), which is technically correct because it lies on the same line as (3,4) due to their matching ratios. However, I am quite confused about the perfect technique to determine the eigenvector when I have a scenario as shown in my snap below. For example, when the simultaneous equation has same numbers:

[image]

```
-4x + 3y = 0 
4x -3y = 0
```

then I could just figure the answer out from one equation alone, however, does this make sense or did it work by fluke. Also, I have noticed that when the numbers in equation 1 and equation 2 are entirely different, I seem to find the answer through the plug in method, which works well too, but I have a gray area in my head. I need someone to tell me the perfect way to find any eigenvector.

For example, if you see my hand written notes, you see that I basically get the eigenvector (0.75,1) through the plugin method because it made sense and it worked, however, I could have gotten (3,4) too but I didn't, since I took a different approach. What is the ideal approach? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One approach isn't really more "valid" than another. Your approach works and is correct. I wouldn't worry too much about it not being "ideal".

Nevertheless, a slightly different approach (in order to avoid fractions) is to try plugging in convenient values. At the end of the problem, your system of linear equations reduces to:
$$
3x_2 = 4x_1
$$
Let's assume the the left hand side and right hand side are both integers. Then since $3$ divides the LHS, it must also divide the RHS. Since $3$ is prime and doesn't divide $4$, it must divide $x_1$. So why not take $x_1$ to be the smallest positive integer that is divisible by $3$ so that $x_1 = 3$. This forces us to take $x_2 = 4$. So our eigenvector is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I see, so my answer is right, and yours too, but I was asking, what is the best approach towards getting non-decimal answers, i.e., getting integer results. Also, in what scenario should I realize that hey, it's time to do plugging in, because for example: if the two equations are identical, it's obvious to solve for one and that's all, you've your values.